# Border radius UIView use shadowPath

Tags: ios

i want set border radius UIView use `shadowPath` to ensure performance not `cornerRadius`.

```
self.testView.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.v.bounds cornerRadius:20.0f] CGPath];
```

but no change!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've set a shadow path and, presumably , nothing else. This will have no visible effect, since if you want a shadow you'll also need to set the colour, radius, opacity and so forth.

If you want to round corners, set the corner radius. I don't know where you've got the impression that using a shadow path for this either works or is faster, it is not.

Using a shadow path improves performance when *using a shadow*. You can't use a corner radius and a shadow on the same layer, since the corner radius clips to bounds, which prevents the shadow drawing. There are plenty of solutions for that if you search.